# python automatic email response system

Tags: python, email, ubuntu

I am planning to create a program(with python) that analyzes and responds to emails on ubuntu, but I cant seem to find anything that could serve as the receiving and sending part of the program(in python, or with terminal commands) does anyone have any suggestions on what I could use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the libraries

- [poplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/poplib.html) and [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) for receiving emails,
- [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html) for sending emails,
- have a look at [email](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) to compose more complex emails.

Answer (score 1):

You want to take a look at [poplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/poplib.html) and [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html).